# Not able to catch on play , pause event of video and audio mediaelement.js in case of IPAD or Iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I am trying the method suggested here [Avoid stoping audio or video](http://css-tricks.com/dont-stop-the-audio/) .

My intention is to Check whether video or audio is playing or not , if its playing all of my links in that page should open in a new tab . Also If the user pause the video or audio then I have to make all links in that page to open in same page .

**Below is my code**

```
 var media = $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({ });
 $(media).on("play", function(event) {

        // Links in new tabs
        $("a").attr("target", "_blank");
        $("a").attr("rel", "external");

    }).on("pause", function(event) {

        // Links in new tabs
        $("a").removeAttr("target");
        $("a").removeAttr("rel");
  });
```

The above code works really well , in case of Google chrome browser , But in case of latest Firefox it doesn’t work at all .

Also My major problem is its not working in non of the Apple devices such as Ipad2 , 3 or 1

Is this a bug of [Mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) or safari browser .

I could easily understand that in case of Firefox or other apple devices , on play or pause event is not caught properly .

Please kindly suggest if there is a work around to solve this .

Thanks in advance for responding to this post .